# Loop Array to find Duplicates

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am trying to figure out why this algorithm isn't working properly.
If I have >= 5 duplicates of one element in my array I want to compress it.
For example:

- I have 10 times the 7 -> output should be = "%" "10" "7"

Expected output should be:

```
{
       "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z",
       "%", "10", "7",
       "M",
       "%", "5", "P",                     
       "H", "H"
    };
```

but I get the new output without "H" "H" it misses Index[20] and Index[21]
So what am I doing wrong?

```
string[] strArray = new string[]
{
    "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z",
    "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7",
    "M",
    "P", "P", "P", "P", "P",
    "H", "H"
};

int counter = 1;
List<string> output = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i <= strArray.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j <= strArray.Length; j++)
    {
        if (strArray [i] == strArray [j])
        {
            counter++;
            i++;
            continue;
        }


        if (counter >= 5)
        {
            add(output, "%");
            add(output, counter.ToString());
            add(output, strArray [i]);
            counter = 1;
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        if (counter < 5)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < counter; n++)
            {
                add(output, strArray [i]);
            }
            counter = 1;
            i++;
        }
    }
}

public static List<string> add(List<string> output, string str)
{
     output.Add(str);
     output;
}

 public static int length(String[] input)
 {
      return input.Length;
 }
```

Comment: Where is `add` defined?

Comment: Why not use a `Dictionary<string, int>` to keep track of the number of times you've encountered a character, then loop over the dictionary values and create your output array?

Comment: @HereticMonkey added sry

Comment: @PranavHosangadi i want to do it with "normal" Loops before i get into dictonaries i want to do it the baby way ^^

Comment: Is this just for adjacent duplicates?  In other words would 7,7,Z,7,7,7 stay the same or would you change it to %,5,7,Z?

Comment: [Here it is in dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z5D7O1) if anyone wants to play around with it and doesn't feel like starting up LINQPad or VS...

Comment: Instead of iterating the array twice why not just keep track of what the previous value and how many times it was seen.  Then you just compare it to the current and either increment the number of times or, you determine how to handle the number of duplicates and reset.  Your problem is almost definitely the fact that you increment `i` in the for loop and internally.

Comment: Honestly, the best way to track down issues like this is just to step through the code line by line in a debugger and keep track of what the variables are.

Comment: @juharr 
for this example dont think to complex just handle the array how it comes like i showed above :)
i dont know what im doing wrong but im missing the last to indexes of my strArray in my Output everything else is like expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's generalize:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Compress(IEnumerable<string> source, int max = 5) {
  int count = 0;
  string prior = null;

  foreach (string item in source) {
    if (count > 0 && prior == item)
      count += 1;
    else {
      if (count >= max) {
        yield return "%";
        yield return count.ToString();
        yield return prior; 
      }
      else  
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
          yield return prior;

      prior = item;
      count = 1; 
    }
  }

  if (count >= max) {
    yield return "%";
    yield return count.ToString();
    yield return prior; 
  }
  else  
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
      yield return prior;
}
```

**Bonus:** Reverse, `Expand` method:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Expand(IEnumerable<string> source) {
  int state = 0;
  int count = 1; 
 
  foreach (string item in source) {
    if (0 == state) 
      if (item == "%")
        state = 1;
      else 
        yield return item;   
    else if (1 == state) {
      count = int.Parse(item);
      state = 2;
    }   
    else {
      for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        yield return item;  

      state = 0;
    }
  }  
}
```

**Demo:**

```
 using System.Linq; // We want .ToArray()
 ...

 string[] strArray = new string[] {
   "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z",
   "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7",
   "M",
   "P", "P", "P", "P", "P",
   "H", "H"
 };

 // ToArray(): since we generalized, 
 // we have to materialize the result; let it be an array 
 string[] result = Compress(strArray).ToArray();
 string[] back = Expand(result).ToArray();

 Console.WriteLine("Initial:    " + string.Join(", ", strArray));
 Console.WriteLine("Compressed: " + string.Join(", ", result));
 Console.WriteLine("Expanded:   " + string.Join(", ", back));
```

**Outcome:**

```
 Initial:    Z, Z, Z, Z, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, M, P, P, P, P, P, H, H
 Compressed: Z, Z, Z, Z, %, 10, 7, M, %, 5, P, H, H
 Expanded:   Z, Z, Z, Z, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, M, P, P, P, P, P, H, H
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `counter` after the inner loop finishes. The inner loop should finish when the strings don't match:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string[] strArray = new string[]
    {
        "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z",
        "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7",
        "M",
        "P", "P", "P", "P", "P",
        "H", "H"
    };

    int counter;
    List<string> output = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
    {
        counter = 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < strArray.Length; j++)
        {
            if (strArray[i] == strArray[j])
            {
                counter++;
                i++;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (counter >= 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("% {0} {1}", counter, strArray[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < counter; n++)
            {
                Console.Write(strArray[i] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Z Z Z Z 
% 10 7
M 
% 5 P
H H
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/7ZT9Nv

https://dotnetfiddle.net/uD06A5 (Example with single loop).